# Navigate to a route multiple times with expo and react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I would like to know how can I set an "infinite" navigation with expo and react native as this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/#navigate-to-a-route-multiple-times.

Currently I would like to navigate between different profil many time and If I use the back history (arrow on the left top) return on the previously profil.
But with the code, from feedPage, if I click on Profil One, Profil Two and Profil One and back I return on the feedPage and not the last profil show (Profil Two).

If I click on Profil One, Profil Two, Profil One and I click on back I would like to see the Profil Two and not the feedPage.

[image]

> index.tsx

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'expo-router';

const FeedPage = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Link href="/feed/settings">Push settings</Link>

            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', gap: 100 }}>
                <Link href="/feed/profil/1">Profil One</Link>
                <Link href="/feed/profil/2">Profil Two</Link>
                <Link href="/feed/profil/3">Profil Three</Link>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default FeedPage;
```

> layout.tsx

```
import { Stack} from "expo-router";

const StackLayout = () => {
    return (
        <Stack>
            <Stack.Screen name="index"  />
        </Stack>
    )
}

export default StackLayout;
```

> profil/[id].tsx

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Stack, useSearchParams } from 'expo-router';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Link } from 'expo-router';

const ProfilPage = () => {
    const { id } = useSearchParams();

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Stack.Screen options={{ headerTitle: `Details #${id}` }} />

            <Text>Profil for: {id}</Text>

            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', gap: 100 }}>
                <Link href="/feed/profil/1">Profil One</Link>
                <Link href="/feed/profil/2">Profil Two</Link>
                <Link href="/feed/profil/3">Profil Three</Link>
            </View>

            <StatusBar style="light" />
        </View>
    );
};

export default ProfilPage;
```

I updated with router.push but same result:

> profil/[id].tsx

```
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Stack, useSearchParams } from 'expo-router';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useRouter } from 'expo-router';

const ProfilPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = useSearchParams();

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Stack.Screen options={{ headerTitle: `Details #${id}` }} />

            <Text>Profil for : {id}</Text>

            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', gap: 100 }}>
                <Button title="Profil One" onPress={() => router.push('/feed/profil/1')} />
                <Button title="Profil Two" onPress={() => router.push('/feed/profil/2')} />
                <Button title="Profil Three" onPress={() => router.push('/feed/profil/3')} />
            </View>

            <StatusBar style="light" />
        </View>
    );
};

export default ProfilPage;
```

packages.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^48.0.7",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-router": "^1.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.27"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "metro": "^0.73.7",
    "metro-resolver": "^0.73.7"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "metro": "^0.73.7",
    "metro-resolver": "^0.73.7"
  },
  "name": "universe-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: use navigation.push instead of navigation.navigate if you want to push a screen to the top of the stack regardless of whether it's in the history or not

Comment: Thx @Abe for your answer! I updated my code, use router.push but same result, very strange..